# Get google account owner from Google Project ID

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-platform

Is it possible to get Google Account Email from the API Project ID? We are using the project id in one of our projects but I am not able to remember the account it was created with?

Comment: Sounds off-topic (not related to programming) here in StackOverflow. I suggest contacting Google directly by filling out this [form](https://support.google.com/code/contact/gcm_dev_support).

Answer (score 4):

Try using the IAM commands in the [Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk) to see who currently is listed as a user/owner:

```
gcloud projects get-iam-policy <your-project-id>
```

That will return a list of current project members.  It may not be the original owner, but this will let you know who all has access :)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am also stuck in same situation .. I tried this but terminal says "User [***@gmail.com] does not have permission to access project [*****:getIamPolicy] (or it may not exist): The caller does not have permission"

Comment: @Anand So you most like want to find out why is project admin, but you can't because you don't have `getIamPolicy` permission which can be granted only by admin...